# Spring Boot throws 404 when serving static HTML from custom static location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am new to Spring Boot and have read over their docs as well as several articles, and am having a difficult time serving a single static HTML page. I *think* what is complicating things here is that I have two requirements that I just can't bend on, and I don't think the docs or these articles address my requirements:

1. I want to use YAML for external config (so `application.yml`); and
2. I actually want my external config to be *external*! That is, I *don't* want it packaged inside my uberjar, rather, I want it to be deployed along with the uberjar, as a decoupled artifact. This allows me to run the same uberjar on any environment where the config file has also been deployed.

So to start with, I have added all the usual Starter POMs on my compile classpath (mentioning this so it is clear that Snake YAML *should* be on my classpath):

```
compile(
    'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'
    ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    ,'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
)
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

Next, I add `src/main/resources/webapps/test.html` to my source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a simple test!
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, I added `application.yml` to the root of my project:

```
spring:
  resources:
    static-locations:
      - 'classpath:/webapps/'
```

The idea is for Spring Boot to find this file in the root dir when running locally, but for the CI server to be able to deploy an arbitrary (environment-specific) `application.yml` alongside the uberjar.

Then I build my uberjar:

```
./gradlew build
```

And now I run my uberjar, passing in a command-line arg which should tell Spring *where* to find my config file:

```
java -Dspring.config.location=. -jar build/libs/myapp.jar
```

I specify "`.`" because Gradle is running out of the project's root directory, which is also where `application.yml` is located.

The app starts up just fine, and when I go to `http://localhost:8080` I see the content that I normally see (I have a `@RestController` that maps `/` to a simple "Hello, Spring Boot" string). **But**, when I go to `http://localhost:8080/test.html`, I get a 404.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Comment: Can you show your controller where `/test` is mapped to?

Comment: normally when you use rest you don't have pathe like http://localhost:8080/test.html you have only http://localhost:8080/test. How is your mapping configured ? can you provide "WebMvcAutoConfiguration" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `src/main/resources` folder is automatically added as a static resource root by Spring Boot auto configuration. This means all folders within it are picked up automatically - you don't need to explicitly add your `webapps` folder.

I just tried this locally by placing `test.html` into the `/main/resources/lestatic/` folder: `http://localhost:8080/test.html` works perfectly with no extra config, and fails with 404 when `classpath:/lestatic/` is specified as resource config.

If this doesn't work, you should check that your `resources` folder is actually included as resource root by your build tool. You can verify that by checking the `target/classes` folder for presence of your custom folder after you complete your build.

See this [Spring Boot manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: Thanks @Yuri (+1) - Two quick questions if you don't mind: **(1)** Is that a typo above? Did you mean to say `/main/resources/static`, or am I really supposed to drop `test.html` into `/main/resources/**lestatic**/`? Thanks for any clarification there! And **(2)** when you say "*...and fails with 404 when `classpath:/webapps/` is specified as resource config...*" can you explain what you mean by "resource config"? I'm just not understanding what you mean by that! Thanks again!

Comment: (1) you can put your `test.html` into any folder that resides within the `src/main/resources` folder

Comment: (2) by _resource config_ I mean the part your YAML configuration (or .properties if you like) where you configure the static resources

Comment: sorry, had a typo in my answer re: 404 when `classpath:/lestatic/` is specified as resource config.

Comment: Thanks again @Yuriy (+1 for all comments) - last question (I promise!). If you specify `classpath:/lestatic/` as a resource config, then why would that cause `http://localhost:8080/test.html` to throw 404s? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. Put you test.html in src/main/resources/**static**/test.html
2. Enjoy! http://localhost:8080/test.html

PS. Also @RestController will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

## tldr;

[Sample Application - GitHub](https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q37498214)

```
gradle build
java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar build/libs/stackoverflow-q37498214.jar
```

**OR**

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar build/libs/stackoverflow-q37498214.jar
```

---

### Profile Specific Properties

Spring Boot supports environment specific configuration via the ${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE} environment variable.

If you set this = ***local*** and then provide a configuration file named ***application-local.yml*** then your Spring Boot application will utilize that environment specific configuration.

You can also set this via the command line:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar build/libs/app.jar
```

Have a look at the Sample Application above and see it in action.

---

### But why 404?

It appears that your custom configuration path (**-Dspring.config.location=.**) isn't being picked up.  And because of that, your custom static-location (**classpath:/webapps/**) aren't being registered and thus not being served by your webserver.

---

If the above solution doesn't work for you, then I would ask you to post a complete example project so we can take a deeper look.  Also, the details of your build process, and how/when you are supplying the production configuration file.